# Selecting title within h3 class - Css Selector using rvest

Tags: r, css-selectors, rvest

I am trying to pull title descriptions using the rvest package in R and SelectorGadget to identify my CSS selectors.

```
<div class="detail">
<h3 class="">                                                                                       
<a href="[].html" 
title="Vasyl Lomachenko Beats Guillermo Rigondeaux" 
class="">Madison Square Garden...</a>
```

Currently using the following code which selects h3 class data: "Madison Square Garden...". I want to select the title data i.e. "Vasyl Lomachenko Beats Guillermo Rigondeaux".

```
url <- 'www.url.com'
webpage <- read_html(url)
Desc <- html_nodes(webpage,'h3') %>% html_text()
```

I have referred to this question below but still can't work it out. Any help would be very welcome!

[Scraping image titles with rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350833/scraping-image-titles-with-rvest)

Comment: Site was boxrec. They have no robot.txt, no T&C/ ToS. Other scrappers seem to collect data from them, so I naively thought it was possible to also collect info. Furthermore, the data I was collecting was to develop a personal project. I wanted to see if boxers that deviated from their average fight weight were more or less likely to beat their opponent. I agree, however, that I should check with the site admin that collecting this info is allowed. Tks for the feedback, didn't mean to drag you into an ethical conflict. http://boxrec.com/media/index.php/Vasyl_Lomachenko_vs._Guillermo_Rigondeaux

Answer (score 1):

Super simple, hadn't used html_attr before:

```
webpage %>% html_nodes("h3 a") %>% html_attr("title")
```