# Extract title with rvest

Tags: r, html-parsing, rvest

I got this xml_nodeset (I don't even know if that's the correct term) from a economic calendar table over at forexfactory.com:

```
<td class="calendar__cell calendar__previous previous">44.7</td>
<td class="calendar__cell calendar__previous previous"><span class="revised worse" title="Revised From -0.6%">-1.1%<span class="icon icon--revised"></span></span></td>
```

In the first case I want to get an empty string or NA, in the second case the value "Revised From -0.6%".

Basically, I want an extra column that is empty if there is no revised value and holds the revised value if there is any.

I tried

`%>% html_attr(x, "title")` and  `%>% html_attrs(x)` inspired by this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350833/scraping-image-titles-with-rvest) without success.

Of course, x holds the xml_node.

Sorry if it's a noob question!

Answer (score 3):

Here in another possible solution.  Two parts find the td nodes and then find the span nodes with the class revised in it.  The function html_node() will return NA if the node is not found thus the number of outputs is equal to the number of inputs.

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html('<td class="calendar__cell calendar__previous previous">44.7</td>
                 <td class="calendar__cell calendar__previous previous">
                 <span class="revised worse" title="Revised From -0.6%">-1.1%
                 <span class="icon icon--revised"></span></span></td>')

#find the td nodes
tdnode <- page %>% html_nodes("td")

#find span nodes within 'td' nodes with the class 'revised'
#Extract the attribute associated with 'title'
tdnode %>% html_node("span.revised") %>% html_attr("title")
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most optimal solution, but it works on your code sample:

```
library(rvest)
tmp <- read_html('<td class="calendar__cell calendar__previous previous">44.7</td>
             <td class="calendar__cell calendar__previous previous"><span class="revised worse" title="Revised From -0.6%">-1.1%<span class="icon icon--revised"></span></span></td>')
tmp2 <- tmp %>% 
  html_nodes("td")
tmp3 <- lapply( tmp2, function(x) {
  tmp4 <- html_children(x)
  ifelse( length(html_attr(tmp4, "title") > 0),
      yes = html_attr(tmp4, "title"),
      no = NA)
    }
  )
unlist(tmp3)
```

Btw do not use `%>% html_attr(x, "title")`, use `%>% html_attr("title")`.